# How load more posts in wordpress post without loading the page with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

On a page template I have created a query for fetching 5 posts and on that custom template I have a load more button. Now I want to load more 3 posts on that page when I will click that button. I have seen a tutoial http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/ here where I can create this system but this tutorial shows for the index.php. But I want this system on my custom template. Right now I have this code in my custom template

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Normal
  */
  get_header();
?>
<?php
    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' =>  'post',
        'posts_per_page'    =>  5
    ));
?>
<div id="content">
    <?php if($loop->have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="load_more">
        <button class="load">Load More</button>
    </div>
</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now what should I do for loading more posts everytime when I will click on the load more button

Comment: Question: how do you expect to get those post without AJAX? Second, I would create a custom posts page, such that you can load x posts, e.g. 3, and skips the already loaded y, e.g. 5. You can then make a ajax call to it, passing the two parameters, and get just the additional posts, loading them into `content`.

Answer (score 1):

That would be impossible without AJAX or a somewhat more involved page reload. One potential workaround would be (if you only have a small number of posts) is to load all the posts and then use CSS to hide the excess ones. Then, use jQuery to add a class (such as `.next-to-appear`) to the first three hidden posts. Then, use jQuery when your button is clicked to make those three appear, remove the `.next-to-appear` class and move it to the next set of three. Not elegant but maybe effective.

Comment: then please tell me the ajax way to do it